# Add exception to Windows Defender at install time

Tags: windows-8, installshield

When running on Windows 8, our application is exceptionally slow unless we add a process exception for it in Windows Defender. (It is mostly from logging operations onto the disk.)

Is there a way to add the exception programmatically during our InstallShield installation? Calling a custom action in C# or VBScript is fine.

Comment: What about all the other possible virusscanners? I would look at changing the behavior of your own code that causes this issue.

Comment: The operation that is slow is simply logging to the %PUBLIC% folder using log4net.  There is not much I can to do change this code!  Our documentation mentions that it is necessary to add exceptions for other virus scanners, but was hoping to add one to the default that is installed with Win8.

Comment: Maybe you can change the behavior of log4net by changing a setting. Like keeping the logfile open instead of opening and closing it hundreds of times which is what is probabaly causing the slowdown.

Comment: Yeah, sorry - I was wrong.  I've realized the logging that is the culprit is not log4net, but a different solution in our older unmanaged code that opens the file each time.  I agree that replacing or enhancing this solution is a better idea, but unfortunately, I don't think I can get buy-in for this in my organization.

Answer (score 1):

Actually i think you look for [Add-MpPreference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/defender/add-mppreference).

Your application is probably slow because you touch a lot of files, and each file you touch gets scanned by the defender.
I use this Powershell command two times, to excluding the exe (-ExclusionProcess) AND the files (-ExclusionPath) during installation.

Answer (score -1):

If it would be so easy to add an exception to Windows Defender by using a VBScript script, Windows Defender would be no protection for your computer because any malware would simply add an exception for itself.

There are some registry keys which define if Windows Defender's real time protection is enabled or not. You can read these values to know if it is active and alert your user that the slowness is caused by Windows Defender. But you cannot modify these keys, not even running in a service with SYSTEM user. These registry keys are protected by Windows to forbid tampering.

Note that since Windows 10 the option to add exceptions to Windows Defender does not exist any more.

The only way to turn on or off Windows Defender:

- Manually via Windows Defender configuration panel (MsAscUi.exe)
- Install another antivirus program which disables Windows Defender automatically.

If you are interested in the registry keys read my answer in another question:

*[Find out if Windows Defender disc scan is running?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/862776/find-out-if-windows-defender-disc-scan-is-running/31306480#31306480)*

Comment: I think this answer is not true anymore, if it was ever.