# How to enable Windows Defender in C#

Tags: c#, windows, msdn

I'm looking for a way to enabled (not disable) Windows Defender in C#.

I found this function on msdn

```
HRESULT WDEnable(
  _In_  BOOL fEnable
);
```

I would be able to use this however its part MpClient.dll, which I cannot find on my system so I can't use LoadLibrary/GetProcAddress/GetDelegateForFunctionPointer

Does anyone know another way to do this?

I should point out that is for legitimate software that needs to check if Windows Defender is enabled(Already coded and working) and if not enable it.

Thanks

Comment: Also just tried using the Registry: HKLM\SYSTEM\ControlSet001\Services\WdNisDrv -> Start and I get an UnauthorizedAccessException

Comment: Found the DLL in C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Defender, I can call the function... but nothing changes =/

Comment: you checked the return value?

Comment: Yes. It returns -2147024891

Comment: That simply means access denied. Read the remarks in the documentation of WDEnable. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb762466.aspx
Pressumably your process doesn't fit into the mentioned prerequisites

Comment: It seems you are right... The app will be used for internal use only so paying for digital signing isn't really an option

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The registry key has some access restrictions for preventing any process which runs in user context to just switch it off. For a virus it would be really easy to prevent it from being detected. To enable it you have to run in a administrator context. Try to run your process as administrator and see if you can change the registry key that way.

From the msdn documentation:
Remarks

> The application calling this function must run with administrator
>   permissions on the local computer. Windows Defender also validates (1)
>   the proper signing of the calling process and all loaded modules and
>   (2) that the IMAGE_DLLCHARACTERISTICS_FORCE_INTEGRITY flag is set on
>   the calling process and all loaded modules before allowing the calling
>   application to change the status. If the calling process image (or any
>   loaded modules) is not signed or is flagged as a threat by the Windows
>   Defender signature, then the call fails with the appropriate error
>   code.

Comment: Yeah I understand that. I always run my developer stuff as admin, it makes no difference

Answer (score 0):

There is no easy way to neither turn on nor turn off Windows Defender via your program. If it would be so easy, Windows Defender would be no protection for your computer because any Malware would simply turn it off.

There are some registry keys which define if Windows Defender's real time protection is enabled or not. You can read these values to know if it is active. But you cannot modify these keys, not even running in a service with SYSTEM user. These registry keys are protected by Windows to forbid tampering.

The only way to turn on or off Windows Defender:

- Manually via Windows Defender configuration panel (MsAscUi.exe)
- Install another antivirus software which disables Windows Defender automatically.

If you are interested in the registry keys read my answer in another thread:
[Find out if Windows Defender disc scan is running?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/862776/find-out-if-windows-defender-disc-scan-is-running/31306480#31306480)

Answer (score 0):

first step is Open the Run dialog box by pressing ‘Windows’ key and ‘R’ key
then Type ‘services.msc’  in the Open dialog box
Press the Enter key or click on the OK button
Check for ‘Security Center’ in the list of services
Right-click on Security Center
Click on Restart